# How to run Spark scala application inside Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to run a simple Spark application using Intellij on Hortonworks sandbox. 
I've opened a new SBT project, then created a Scala class:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "/root/temp.txt"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    println(logData .count())
  }
}
```

This is my the build.sbt:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "1.3.0" % "provided"
```

Now right clicking on this class -> run throws exception :

```
exception in thread main java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org/apache/Spark/SparkConf
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I can see spark libraries on the dependencies list. Any help? (BTW running this program through SBT Scala console works perfectly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
object SimpleApp extends App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "/root/temp.txt"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    println(logData .count())
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications), this is incorrect: "Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly" Furthermore, adding `main` and extending `App` are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.sbt` file, you need two percent signs:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.2" % "provided"`

to specify the Scala version of the artifact `spark-core`.

To run your class in IntelliJ IDEA, you need to also add the Spark library through "File -> Project Structure". Then, under "Libraries", you can add the necessary Spark libs.

Note that objects should not extend `App` as per the [Spark QuickStart](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/quick-start.html)

> Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.

Edit 1: You can also temporarily remove the `provided` qualifier while testing.