# scala spark notebook inside IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook

I use [andypetrella/spark-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/andypetrella/spark-notebook/), and it's great:

```
docker run -p 9001:9001 andypetrella/spark-notebook:0.7.0-scala-2.11.8-spark-2.1.0-hadoop-2.7.3
```

However, I would like to use such a notebook from inside InteliJ to use completion and debugging. How to achieve this?

I see the IntelliJ you can have New -> jupyter, but I think it is only python. Or does it work on scala and spark?

I also see that IntelliJ has a Scala worksheet. With its [experimental REPL](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2017/03/23/scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea-2017-1-cleaner-ui-sbt-shell-repl-worksheet-akka-support-and-more/), IntelliJ evaluates incrementally the new lines added, but it evaluates all the file from the beginning if you change a line in the middle of the file. So, not very convinient compared to a jupyter notebook.

I see other questions about running scala spark notebook inside IntelliJ, such as this one, but they do not answer the question here.
[How to run Spark scala application inside Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715434/how-to-run-spark-scala-application-inside-intellij)

The question is how to have the equivalent of [andypetrella/spark-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/andypetrella/spark-notebook/) from inside IntelliJ (so, only evaluate the lines changed)?

Answer (score 1):

As for spark notebook in Intellij I am afraid you are out of luck. 
If you want any notebook with Spark in Intellij then you can test Apache **Zeppelin** notebook. The plugin works but is outdated.

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 dylanmei/zeppelin
```

- In Intellij Plugins->Browse repositories-> search IntelliJ Zeppelin
- Create an empty scala class and inside it type 'NotebookName'
- Hit ctrl+shift+alt+enter (shift+option+cmd+enter) (see tools-> Zeppelin in the intellij menu for shortcuts)- this should give you a window asking for the address of zepellin
- Type the code for the paragraph
- shift+alt+enter (shift+option+enter) to add the paragraph. This should give you the result of the paragraph
- Navigate to http://localhost:8080 (or whatever port you gave it) and look for 'NotebookName' (if you do not give it a name it will spawn as 'IntelliJ Notebook')

There is a demo of this on the plugins github: https://github.com/chilang/intellij-zeppelin

If you try to use this plugin with spark-notebook it will yield a nasty error.